# How can I check if certificates generated with openssl are vulnerable to heartbleed

Tags: security, ssl-certificate, openssl, heartbleed

I am aware that you can show the version of openssl you are using by typing the following at the command line "openssl version".

I created a certificate and a key some time ago with similar names to server.cer and server.key.

The problem I have is that I am not sure what version of openssl they have been created with. Is there command you can use to find what version of openssl they were created with ? Do the certificates and keys store this information.

I am trying to confirm if they are vulnerable to the openssl heartbleed security issue.

Comment: You should better check if your servers are running a vulnerable openssl version and patch those. After that, you can worry about getting new certificates.

Answer (score 16):

A certificate isn't vulnerable, or otherwise, to heartbleed.  A certificate is just a certificate.  There have been crypto issues in the past, particularly with respect to the RNG of choice, that caused weak keys (and thus vulnerable certificates) to be created, but heartbleed isn't a vulnerability of that type.

A key/certificate pair can have been compromised by heartbleed, irrespective of the version of OpenSSL with which it was created or even if it was created by a completely different SSL implementation, if it was used on a server that offered TLS services to the public using a vulnerable version of OpenSSL.

If it was not so used, it cannot have been compromised by heartbleed, even if it was created on a server that at that time was running a vulnerable version of OpenSSL.

(Now for the life's-more-complicated-than-you-would-like bit: **if** you created the key/certificate pair (or key/CSR pair) on a server **and** that server was at that time running a vulnerable version of OpenSSL **and** you were connected to that server by a method vulnerable to exploit (eg OpenVPN, but not OpenSSH) **and** you exposed the contents of the created keyfile to the connection stream, eg by cat'ing the file or by copying it over the connection, **then** it is possible that the certificate could have been compromised.  But that's still not a vulnerability in the *certificate* as such, and it's not detectable by examination of the certificate (or any other way, as far as I am aware).